# could not find function "get_timeline_"

Tags: r, twitter, word-cloud

I am trying to create a wordcloud with data from Twitter in rstudio, but after installing the packages (called them all with library and got my access through API keys) I get the same error over and over when I am trying to search for a specific account. This error keeps coming up:

could not find function "get_timeline_"

I am currently following this tutorial https://mikeyharper.uk/creating-twitter-wordclouds/

```
library(NLP)
library(qdapRegex)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rtweet)
library(SnowballC)
library(stringr)
library(tm)
library(twitteR)
library(usethis)
library(wordcloud)
library(wordcloud2)

tweets_NameOfPage <- get_timelines(c("NameOfPage"), n = 3200)
```

Comment: Try with `get_timelines`

Comment: @Phil that doesn´t work either, getting almost the same error                                
                                                                                                                                 
 could not find function "get_timelines"

Comment: Could you provide the code exactly as you have tried? (don't provide your API key). I can replicate the code from the blog post without a problem.

Comment: @Phil > library(NLP)
> library(qdapRegex)
> library(RColorBrewer)
> library(rtweet)
> library(SnowballC)
> library(stringr)
> library(tm)
> library(twitteR)

Attaching package: ‘twitteR’

The following object is masked from ‘package:rtweet’:

    lookup_statuses

> library(usethis)
> library(wordcloud)
> library(wordcloud2)
> consumer_key = 'xxx'
> consumer_secret = 'xxx'
> access_token = 'xxx'
> access_token_secret = 'xxx'
> 
> tweets_NameOfPage <- get_timelines(c("NameOfPage"), n = 3200)

Comment: Remove `library(twitteR)` and try again.

Comment: @AnnabelLuijerink was that the answer / helpful? I did wonder why you were using twitterR and rTweet in the same set of code - rTweet is the one that is more maintained.